# Facebook App Vanity Name (More Than 1000 Likes)

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-apps

Now that my facebook app has got more than 1000 likes -- https://apps.facebook.com/156485447732146/

But I still can't find how to get the vanity name for it as http://apps.facebook.com/Bizspeaking/ , it's ridiculous that getting the name is even harder than building the app...

(Note I've already got my vanity Facebook page as http://www.facebook.com/Bizspeaking , but haven't figured out how to link the two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a property inside the app settings called `app namespace`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, never thought that is the key.

Comment: Yea - The tooltip also doesnt shed much light on it.